# Discrete Math: Question regarding functions/combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I'm having some trouble getting a viable answer to the following question:

Let $A$ = {$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$}

How many functions $f: A→A$ are there so that $f(1)=2$?

I believe the best way to solve this problem is to find the total number of functions ($9^9$) and subtract the number of functions such that $f(1)$ does not equal $2$.  But I am not sure how to find that value.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You can simply map $1$ out of $9$ values to each of the $9-1=8$ values in $\{2,\dots,9\}$ (i.e., $9^8$ functions).

Answer (score 1):

Simply map one of the $9$ values in $\{1,\dots,9\}$ to each one of the $8$ values in $\{2,\dots,9\}$:

- $f(1)=2$
- $f(2)\in[1,9]$
- $f(3)\in[1,9]$
- $f(4)\in[1,9]$
- $f(5)\in[1,9]$
- $f(6)\in[1,9]$
- $f(7)\in[1,9]$
- $f(8)\in[1,9]$
- $f(9)\in[1,9]$

This yields a total of $9^8$ functions.